# Dynamic Personal Finance Functions CountIfs and Sequence

Tags: excel, date, sequence

For many years, I have used excel for a personal finance budget. I have made many incremental improvements over time. The current format includes:

-Report Start Date
-Report End Date
-List of
Income or expense description | amount | start date | end date | frequency of payment (daily/weekly/biweekly/bimonthly/monthly/quarterly/annually)
-36 Future Months (begin date, end date)

I recently started playing with the SEQUENCE function and realized I could easily create a list of dates basted on an income/expense start date | end date | and frequency. Then, using COUNTIFS, I could filter by month so the report will generate the number of payments per month and multiply out by that period. Ultimately, I will sum it all up for a complete personal finance view.

Where I am stuck: I can create the list of payment dates with sequence in one cell, and use COUNTIFS to generate the number of payments in another cell (referencing the SEQUENCE results with a hashtag). But, if I replace the reference to the SEQUENCE cell with the SEQUENCE formula into the criteria range of the COUNTIFS, the COUNTIFS function returns an error message.

Questions:
(1) is this the best approach?
(2) is there a way to change the formula so it works?

Assuming Daily Frequency,
D5 is payment end date
C5 is start date
G5# is a reference to the cell with the Sequence function
G3 is the monthly period start date
G4 is the monthly period end date
=SEQUENCE(D5-C5+1,1,C5,1)

```
=COUNTIFS(G5#,">="&G3,G5#,"<="&G4)
```

Below is what the report looks like. The graduated orange cells show the flow of the formulas. Can they be consolidated to a single cell? Or, is there a better way to approach this?

[image: Report example]

Comment: COUNTIFS() use ranges exclusively in the reference.  It does not accept arrays, which is why it fails when trying to use sequence directly.  You can probably switch to SUMPRODUCT that will accept arrays.

Comment: Actually SUMPRODUCT will not work here either.  Sorry.